# Sublime Text 3 Glue package, setting shellpath with arguments

Tags: git, sublimetext3

I'm trying set custom shell path in Glue package and use it with arguments.

Point is, that on Windows I dont want to use native powershell or so, I want to use Git Bash, that is installed.

sh.exe needs to be run with argumens --login -i but settings below does not work in Glue:

```
{
    "glue_shellpath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\bin\\sh.exe --login -i"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick look through [`Glue`'s source](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/glue) seems to indicate that the `"glue_shellpath"` command can only be a single filename, without any arguments. The easiest way around this is to make a batch file. Create a file with the following contents:

```bat
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

and save it as `runloginshell.bat` in your `Git\bin` directory (you can save it anywhere, really). Then, set

```json
"glue_shellpath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\bin\\runloginshell.bat"
```

in your `Glue.sublime-settings` file, and hopefully you should be all set. Remember that `.sublime-settings` files need to be valid [JSON](http://json.org), so make sure you have appropriately-placed commas at the end of all lines except the last one, and that everything is enclosed in `{ }` curly braces.

Good luck!

Comment: I got this to work using this method, and then converting the `runloginshell.bat` to an executable using a Bat to Exe converter.

But, the problem was that glue starts up a new shell instance everytime, so each output included the initializing git-bash output, and the logout output. In addition, the colors were not shown, instead outputted in ASCII.